# Scaffolding a React Native and React web project

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm at the starting phase of a project that is going to use React Native and React to spit out a build for iOS, Android and web that has a consistent feel. My question is: what's the best way to do this? Should I build the app in React Native and then work on porting a web build? It seems like ReactXP kind of does this, but also includes Windows stuff that we just don't need. Or is it just easier to completely separate the native from the web.

Thank you in advance for the advice!

Comment: It seems like just keeping web and native apps separate is the way to go. React Native was developed to write native apps using React and Javascript, rather than provide a platform for code sharing, though it is possible with HOC and others, as discussed in the attached links.

Additional Links: 
https://hackernoon.com/code-reuse-using-higher-order-hoc-and-stateless-functional-components-in-react-and-react-native-6eeb503c665

http://ihor.burlachenko.com/code-sharing-between-react-and-react-native-applications/

Comment: Also already asked [and answered] here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43869727/can-we-share-code-between-react-webapp-and-react-native-app-and-is-react-native